# Using set_config in CTE

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I want to be able to call `set_config` to set a configuration parameter within the same transaction/scope as an INSERT statement.  There is a function triggered AFTER the insert which reads from this configuration parameter.

I need to accomplish this as a single statement so CTEs seems like a good idea:

```sql
WITH 
  idx AS (SELECT set_config('audit.trace_id', '123', true)), 
  rows AS (INSERT INTO "person" ("name") values ('Mary') RETURNING *) 
SELECT * FROM rows
```

However, it seems `audit.trace_id` is not available to the trigger function.  So then I thought I'd structure it like below, which should create a dependency:

```sql
WITH 
  idx AS (SELECT set_config('audit.trace_id', '123', true)) 
INSERT INTO "person" ("name") values ('Mary') RETURNING *
```

But still, the value in `audit.trace_id` is still not set within scope of the triggered function.  I believe this is because Postgre avoids running the SELECT as the result isn't required further into the CTE.

If I select out from both, like below, then `audit.trace_id` is successfully set when the trigger function runs:

```sql
WITH 
  idx AS (SELECT set_config('audit.trace_id', '123', true) as __trace_id),
  row as (INSERT INTO "person" ("name") values ('Mary') RETURNING *)
SELCET * FROM idx, row
```

**Question**

Is 'audit.trace_id' guaranteed to be set by the time the trigger executes on the person table?  Or is there a possible race condition here?

**EDIT:**

What about this?  It seems to work fine:

```sql
INSERT INTO "person" ("name") values ('Mary') RETURNING *, set_config('audit.trace_id', '123', true)
```

Comment: idx is not used in your main query and skipped

Comment: The smart and correct way to do this is to run two separate SQL statements.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Agreed, but I am constrained to one query in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, within a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-cte/), the queries are not guaranteed to be executed in the order they are written, they are optimized by the PostgreSQL engine and might be executed in parallel or in a different order that might not be expected.
However, [data-modifying statements in `WITH`](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/postgresql/with-query) are executed exactly once, and always to completion, which does mean that they will always fully complete before the main query starts to run.

Given your constraints and the problems you are facing, it seems that the final solution you proposed:

```sql
INSERT INTO "person" ("name") values ('Mary') RETURNING *, set_config('audit.trace_id', '123', true)
```

would be the most reliable way to ensure the configuration parameter `'audit.trace_id'` is set before the trigger function executes, as it sets the configuration parameter during the `INSERT` statement's `RETURNING` clause, essentially making it a part of the data modification statement, ensuring it is executed within the same transaction and before any `AFTER INSERT` triggers.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL executes the CTE `idx` only if it is referenced in the main statement. That's why your third attempt was successful, unlike the first two.

The placeholder parameter will certainly be set by the time an `AFTER INSERT` trigger executes, because the CTE has to be executed before the `INSERT`.

There cannot be any race conditions, because the execution plan is deterministic, and no parallel processing is taking place. `set_config` is marked `PARALLEL UNSAFE`, so a statement containing it will never be executed using parallel query.